# How HeapMemoryUsagePercent is Calculated in JDK Mission Control (JMC)?

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, jmc

I wrote a program using JMX API to calculate JVM Usage percentage. Code makes use of 2 attributes of *java.lang:type=Memory* MBean (*used and max attribute*).

When I use the formula (*used/max * 100*) to calculate JVM Used Memory Percent, it gives me very different value than what is displayed in JMC Software. For example:

In JMC I see the Percentage as 45.3%. But used = 708MB and max = 6GB, which in turn in my code gives very less percentile.
[image]

From Task Manager > Process Tab > Memory Column, I looked for the corresponding TomEE memory usage which is closed to the usage attribute in JMC.

[image]

Need some guidance here on what is the right way to calculate or look for the JVM Usage Percentage. Why there is a difference of percentage in JMC attribute (HeapMemoryUsagePercent) and the percentage calculation in my code?

Comment: There is no "right" way. All these numbers have meaning, so take those that important to *you*. JMC calculates used percentage here as `Heap Used` / `Heap Committed`.

Comment: Thanks apangin. I will use committed and max attribute to check for free jvm left, this pretty much fulfills my requirement.